# Simulating a security layer for the LIN bus without physical devices

Tags: simulation, bus

I am trying to test out some proposed Security layers for the Local Interconnect Network (LIN) Bus protocol. For example by hasing the data that the slaves send, by the means of a symetric key.
My plan is to try out different approaches and gather data on how well they perform in deiffernt simulated networks.

I have looked at simualtion tools like CANoe and CanEasy, however they don't seem to allow me to modify how the protocol sends messages. I have now tried using TSMaster which seems to allow me more access to how the protocol actually works, but I am finding it hard to get the python mini programs to work.

Can anyone tell me if its actually possible to do this in TSMaster? If not then maybe a LIN Bus framework that I could use to the same effect?